# How to Use Work Manager to keep the Broadcast Receiver alive?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, android-workmanager

I created an Android application to get all the call logs after the user ends the call. I used Broadcast Receiver to identify the changes then Run the service to get the information about the last call. But sometimes App is killed by the system after one or two days. I read the `Broadcast` Documentation, Android `Service` Documentation, and `Android <OREO  Restriction`. Is there any way to keep the Call Broadcast Receiver all the time?

**Is there any way to use work manager?**

**Is there any good approaches, please share here**

> Service class

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    
            Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, HammerService.class);
            context.startForegroundService(startServiceIntent);
    
            }
    }
```

> Service class

```
public class HammerService extends Service {


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter();
        ifilter.addAction(android.telephony.TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED);

        registerReceiver(receiver, ifilter);

    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        String input = intent.getStringExtra("inputExtra");
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Hammer Service")
                .setContentText(input)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_android)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();

        startForeground(1, notification);

        //do heavy work on a background thread
        //stopSelf();
        return START_NOT_STICKY;

    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if(action.equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")){
                //action for sms received
            }
            else if(action.equals(android.telephony.TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED)){
                runfirstTime(context,intent);
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions), `ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED` is on the implicit broadcast exemptions list. Are you sure that you cannot receive this broadcast from a receiver registered in the manifest?

Comment: Thanks a lot for reading this Question  . It stops after one / two days, actually, I was developed one Call Logs monitoring App to get Call logs after the user ends the call. (Because according to my requirement, the user may delete the call logs),  inorder to ignore that, I was trying to save in the local, then it will automatically update into the server.  can use this, can I use onetime work request (workmanager). please tell any kind of approaches i will follow that ❤️

Comment: "It stops after one / two days, actually" -- your service stops. I am suggesting that you may not need the service, as it looks like you should be able to register for this broadcast in the manifest. If that does not work, I think that you are in trouble, as newer versions of Android do not let you start a foreground service from the background, such as via `WorkManager`.

Comment: Please give me time, I will try without foreground service and Service, I don't like to waste your time, I will try and message here. Thanks a lot for your valuable time. Respect 

Comment: @CommonsWare I implemented an app, which is notifying the `ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED`, It's successfully working in my Emulator, but after I get the app into my RealDevice(MI -Android 10Q ). After close the app. it did not work. This is my tried code https://github.com/prasath95/Keep-Alive-the-Broadcast-Receiver- .  Please check Thank you

Comment: "but after I get the app into my RealDevice(MI -Android 10Q ). After close the app. it did not work" -- some device manufacturers have restrictions above and beyond those in Android itself. I cannot comment on those, as there are too many manufacturers with too many devices. You might consider examining Logcat on that phone to see if there are any logging messages from the system that might explain the difference in behavior.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks, I will search on that

Comment: @CommonsWare Dear expert, I also met this issue manifest registered Receiver stopped working after app got killed. From your comment I know this is not expected behavior. I want to trigger my notification every time new image(camera, screenshot or download) is saved to storage. Don't want foreground service which always have a notification there. Is this a feasible? Thanks.

Comment: @gg: "Is this a feasible?" -- no, sorry.

Comment: @FGH Have you found any solution? I'm facing the same issue with manifest declared broadcast receiver for reading sms `SMS_RECEIVED`. In some mobiles after few hours app process was killed may be because of battery optimzations. I only used the broadcast receiver and no services or job schedulers. Please let me know if you find any solution. Struggling from few days.